Searchkick as a client only
I'm working at a Ruby software which is divided in services (not micro, just services). Some of these services have the Searchkick gem installed (https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) and index data by calling the usual Searchkick methods in the models.
Then I have a Search service, in charge of performing these searches, which doesn't have any model.
Is there a way to use Searchkick and its beautiful API as a client only, without the indexing part. I'm really struggling, even if I just attempt to create empty classes it fails apparently searching for data in my database - which I don't have.
Thanks in advance.

As far as I understand you want to leverage Searchkick's querying API without using its indexing features.You can config Searchkick to act in a read-only mode
searchkick callbacks: false


I wouldn't say it's read only, because when you search something it returns models, but I have no models...

class Bla; searchkick callbacks: false; end; this is what I would have.... What I would like is something that doesn't need the data layer, and just returns whatever OpenSearch returns
